# How to parse JSON property as Map key in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, dictionary, type-conversion

I want to parse JSON property as a Map key.
Here is JSON string:

```
const jsonString = `{
    "DDBProps": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "test": "2",
        "prod": "100"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "test": "2",
        "prod": "100"
      }
    },
    "DDBProps2": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "test": "2",
        "prod": "200"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "test": "2",
        "prod": "200"
      }
    }
}`
```

So, I want these "DDBProps", "DDBProps2", ... "DDBPropsX" to be a Map key, and value to be nested Map. Essentially, something like `Map<string, Map<string, Map<string, string>>>`. I want this nest map structure because I need to get the number (e.g. "2", "100", "200" in this JSON) based on the input: `DDBPropsType, region, stage`.

So I declared interfaces:

```
interface ThroughputMap {
    throughputMappings: Map<string,RegionMap>
}

interface RegionMap {
    regionMappings: Map<string, StageMap>
}

interface StageMap {
    stageMappings: Map<string, string>
}

// parse
const ddbScaleMap: ThroughputMap = JSON.parse(ddbScalingMappingsJson);
```

However, this doesn't parse the JSON to correct structure:

```
console.log(ddbScaleMap)
// output below
{
    "DDBProps": {
      "us-east-1": {"test": "2","prod": "100"},
      "us-west-2": {"test": "2","prod": "100"}
    },
    "DDBProps2": {
      "us-east-1": {"test": "2","prod": "200"},
      "us-west-2": {"test": "2","prod": "200"}
    }
}


console.log(ddbScaleMap.throughputMappings) // output undefined
```

I can't parse property as Map key.

### I tried:

```
const ddbScaleMap = new Map<string, Map<string, Map<string, string>>>(Object.fromEntries(JSON.parse(jsonString)))
```

This didn't parse correctly in nested value. Meaning, `ddbScaleMap.get("DDBProps").get("us-west-2");` .get("us-west-2") cannot be called.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do the conversion for you. You have to convert it yourself in JS - then cast the result to the desired type.

Comment: I don't know if the JSON parsing part of this is actually relevant; presumably `JSON.parse(jsonString)` gives you something to work with.  The important part is how to convert a plain object into nested `Map`s (not sure *why* you need that, but you're the boss).  That could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXq4LN). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: And here's my more [unsafe take](https://tsplay.dev/wOAjdm).

Comment: Hey thank you so much for replying. So why do I need this: I need to get a number based on the input from the user. So user can decide which DDBProps, which region, which stage they want. I can only think this is possible by Map where I can do map.get(ddbPropInput)?.get(regionInput)?.get(stageInput);. Is there any better way or practices?
Also, yes that is what I needed! @jcalz.

Comment: @caTS Yes, that is the desired result. But could I ask why that would be a unsafe take?

Comment: You are basically going in blindfolded and then reaching for the result and labeling it the correct type regardless of what the actual result is. So, I'd only use it if you are 100% sure that it is correct.

Comment: Why not just access the object? `object[ddbPropInput]?.[regionInput]?.[stateInput]`?

Comment: I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. If you have any suggestion for alternative approach to accomplish the needs (get number based on inputs) besides converting it to the map, that would also be amazing!

Comment: "besides converting it to the map"? Wait, if you don't need to do that, I'm not sure what the question is about. You can just access properties directly, since it's a plain object, like `obj["DDBProps"]["us-east-1"]["prod"]`. Why are you using a Map in the first place?  If this is an XY problem and the underlying need is just "deep indexing into an object" then converting to maps is not needed.  So, is the question: "how do you convert an object into a nested `Map` structure?" or "how do you deep index into an object"? I will wait to hear back (@jcalz) before I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, there is a way to access nested value easily without converting to a map. In TS, you use `keyof typeof` to access nested value like this:

```
function getThroughputByKey(key: string, region: string, stage: string): number {
    const defaultThroughputValue = 1;

    const regionToStageMap = ddbScalingMappingsObject[key as keyof typeof ddbScalingMappingsObject];
    const stageToThroughputMap = regionToStageMap[region as keyof typeof regionToStageMap];
    const throughputString = stageToThroughputMap[stage as keyof typeof stageToThroughputMap];
    const throughput = Number(throughputString);

    return throughput || defaultThroughputValue;
}
```